# How to update the UI - JetpackCompose

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I have a problem and I can’t figure it out. What's wrong in my code. There is an UIScreen for displaying the list of Tasks. I am fetching those tasks from my repository into the viewmodel and then passing the changes into screen. But this does not seem to work. Can someone please guide me how to get the code be working, and tell me what techniques I can use so that the same mistakes doesn’t repeat. THANKYOU!

SCREEN->

```kotlin
@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun TaskListScreen(
    viewModel: TaskListViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    onNavigate: (UiEvent.Navigate) -> Unit
) {
    val swipeRefreshState = rememberSwipeRefreshState(isRefreshing = viewModel.state.isRefreshing)
    val state = viewModel.state

    val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }


    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
        viewModel.uiEvent.collect { event ->
            when (event) {
                is UiEvent.Navigate -> {
                    onNavigate(event)
                }

                is UiEvent.showSnackBar -> {
                    val result = snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(event.message, event.action)
                    if (result == SnackbarResult.ActionPerformed) {
                        viewModel.onEvent(TaskListEvents.UndoDelete)
                    }

                }

                else -> Unit
            }

        }
    }

    Scaffold(
        snackbarHost = { snackbarHostState },
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(
                onClick = {
                    viewModel.onEvent(TaskListEvents.OnAddTaskClick)
                },
                containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary
            ) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Filled.Add,
                    contentDescription = "Add Task",
                    tint = Color.White
                )

            }
        },
        floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.End
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            OutlinedTextField(
                value = state.searchQuery,
                onValueChange = {
                    viewModel.onEvent(TaskListEvents.OnSearchQueryChanged(it))
                },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(16.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                placeholder = {
                    Text(text = "Search...")
                },
                maxLines = 1,
                singleLine = true
            )
            SwipeRefresh(
                swipeEnabled = true,
                state = swipeRefreshState,
                onRefresh = { viewModel.onEvent(TaskListEvents.RefreshTasks) },
            ) {
                if (state.tasks.isEmpty()) {
                    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
                        Text(
                            text = "There are no tasks yet. Add tasks to view them here.",
                            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        )
                    }
                } else {
                    LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                        items(state.tasks.size) { i ->
                            val task = state.tasks[i]
                            TaskListItem(
                                task = task,
                                event = viewModel::onEvent,
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .fillMaxWidth()
                                    .clickable {
                                        viewModel.onEvent(TaskListEvents.OntaskItemClicked(task))
                                    }
                                    .padding(16.dp)
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Repository ->

```kotlin
 override suspend fun getAllTask(date: String): Flow<Resource<List<TaskEntity>>> {
        return flow {
            emit(Resource.Loading(true))
            try {
                val result = dao.getAlltask(date)
                emit(
                    Resource.Success(data = result)
                )
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                emit(
                    Resource.Error(
                        "Some unexpected error has occurred, try adding the task again if not visible"
                    )
                )
            }
            emit(Resource.Loading(false))

        }
    }
```

viewModel ->

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class TaskListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: TaskRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _uiEvent = Channel<UiEvent>()
    val uiEvent = _uiEvent.receiveAsFlow()

    var state by mutableStateOf(TaskListState())
        private set
//    private var _state = TaskListState()
//    var state: TaskListState by mutableStateOf(_state)
//        private set

    init {
        refreshTasks()
    }

    private var searchJob: Job? = null

    private var deletedTask: TaskEntity? = null

    fun onEvent(event: TaskListEvents) {
        when (event) {
            is TaskListEvents.ToggleDone -> {
                viewModelScope.launch {
                    repository.updateTask(
                        event.taskItem.copy(
                            isDone = event.isDone
                        )
                    )
                }
            }

            is TaskListEvents.OntaskItemClicked -> {
                sendUiEvent(UiEvent.Navigate(ScreenRoutes.TaskDetailScreen.route + "?id=${event.taskItem.id}"))
            }

            is TaskListEvents.OnAddTaskClick -> {
                sendUiEvent(UiEvent.Navigate(ScreenRoutes.TaskDetailScreen.route))
            }

            is TaskListEvents.RefreshTasks -> {
                refreshTasks()
            }

            is TaskListEvents.OnDeleteClicked -> {
                viewModelScope.launch {
                    deletedTask = event.taskItem
                    repository.deleteTask(event.taskItem)
                }
                UiEvent.showSnackBar("Todo deleted", "Undo")
            }

            is TaskListEvents.UndoDelete -> {
                viewModelScope.launch {
                    repository.insertTask(deletedTask!!)
                }
                deletedTask = null
            }

            is TaskListEvents.OnSearchQueryChanged -> {
                state = state.copy(searchQuery = event.search)
                searchJob?.cancel()
                searchJob = viewModelScope.launch {
                    delay(500L)
                    repository.searchTask(state.searchQuery, getDateToString())
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private fun refreshTasks() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.getAllTask(getDateToString())
                .collect { result ->
                    when (result) {
                        is Resource.Success -> {
                            result.data?.let { tasks ->
                                state = state.copy(
                                    tasks = tasks,
                                    isLoading = false
                                )
                            }
                        }

                        is Resource.Error -> {
                            state = state.copy(
                                error = result.message ?: "",
                                isLoading = false
                            )

                        }

                        is Resource.Loading -> {
                            state = state.copy(isLoading = true)
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    private fun sendUiEvent(event: UiEvent) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _uiEvent.send(event)
        }
    }

}
```

P.S: Using a data class taskState to maintain everything.

```kotlin
data class TaskListState(
    val tasks : List<TaskEntity> = emptyList(),
    val isLoading : Boolean = false,
    val searchQuery :String = "",
    val error : String = "",
    val isRefreshing : Boolean = false
)
```

I tried playing with remember mutable state but not understanding what exactly the problem is.

Comment: What is the main problem you are facing now? Seeing your code, it seems your screen is in Loading state. Is this the case?

Comment: The main problem is that i have to refresh everytime i update something. The changes aren't getting auto updated. Suppose i add a task, and when i go back to home screen, i have to manually refresh the screen to see the updated list on tasks. Normally it should get auto updated and shown on the home screen.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a

```
private val _text = MutableStateFlow("")
val text = _text.asStateFlow()
```

in your viewmodel.
and when you want to update it do

```
_text.update {"new text"}
```

and in your UI do

```
val text = vm.text.collectAsState()
```